# Can I change a Image RefreshControl's image in react-native?

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

I want to use Custom image to use refreshcontrols.

But I have no idea. And I spend two days.

I want to use flatlist is using Animated.

How can I do It?

Comment: take a look at this article: https://medium.com/@lennyboyatzis/custom-pull-to-refresh-animations-in-react-native-1efac58609d3

Comment: Thank you I will try it.

Comment: @SelmiKarim It does not work on android